# <select> menu and PHP

Tags: php, selection

I am using a  menu to try to get data into a DB.
I have seen this,

```
<select name="exam" id="exam" style="background-color: #FFDDF4">
   <option></option>
   <?php foreach($exams as $key=>$option):
      $selected = ($exam == $key) ? 'selected' : '';
      echo "<option value='$key' $selected>$option</option>";
   endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Without this line,

```
$selected = ($exam == $key) ? 'selected' : '';
```

is it possible to get a chosen value into the DB?
Is the variable $exam the actual name of the select element?

Thanks,
Shane

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get the data into the database - you could leave that line out and it would still submit it to the database.

The variable "exams" is an array structure containing all the options to display on the screen. It is not the name of the select element.  The select element is defined by name="exam"  in the first line, ie it is "exam".

I've not come across the line in question before, but it is quite clearly setting the "selected" field on a particular option.  This "selected" field is then used as a default, but other then displaying it as the default option, it has no importance when the form is actually submitted.

Lets break down the elements of your code relevant to a web query:

The  at the beginning defines that the field is a selection box.  The name, id and style fields are used for formatting the way the page looks, so are not relevant to the submitting back of the data.

This defines the dropdown option in the field field to be empty initially.  Presumably this is used if someone has not attempted to fill out the form before.

```
   <?php foreach($exams as $key=>$option):
      $selected = ($exam == $key) ? 'selected' : '';
      echo "<option value='$key' $selected>$option</option>";
   endforeach; ?>
```

This is where it gets interesting.
$exams is almost certainly going to be an array, so a variable structure - below would be an example of a possible structure, which I'll use for my answer.

```
$exams['English']='English 101';
$exams['Maths']='Calculus';
$exams['Science']='Lab Experiments';
```

The "foreach" tells PHP to go through each element in the array, defining a key and option value.

Thus the first time it loops (given my array) above, the first time through the loop, $key would be "English" and the value would be "English 101".  The second time $key would be "Maths", value would be "Calculus" and so on.

```
echo "<option value='$key' $selected>$option</option>";
```

writes the HTML code, so when viewed by the browser it will look like
English 101
Calculus
Lab Experiments

This will then display "English 101", "Calculus" and "Lab Experiments" in the browser, but when the form is submitted it will post a value of "English","Maths" or "Science", depending on what was selected.

the $selected would (I'm guessing) not be used the first time the page is displayed, however if the page has been viewed and is being displayed back to the user - for example if its done some error checking and found errors but wants to show the form as it received it - then the $selected would have the value "selected" for the option the user previously selected, otherwise it would be blank.   This would tell the browser to show the appropriate field.

The endforeach presumably finishes the iteration.  (The syntax used here is again different to what is typical - normally you would just use braces).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this answer is  great. "you could leave that line out and it would still submit it to the database." is what I really needed to hear. Also thanks for clarifying that $exam is an array and not the name of the element. Brilliant answer, much appreciated.